# How do you search all source code in Vim?

Tags: vim, grep

When using Vim, and given a directory filled with code (e.g. ~/trunk/) with a number of sub-directories, is there a way to grep/search for instances of text/regexes across the entire source code?

At the moment I use:

```
:lcd ~/trunk
:grep "pattern" *.py */*.py */*/*.py */*/*/*.py
```

(Obviously I'm limiting this to Python files, which is a different issue, but it's noteworthy that ideally I'd like to limit the searches to files with specific extensions.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
:vimgrep "pattern" ~/trunk/**/*.py
:copen 20
```

If you have quite a big project I'd recommend to you to use [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) and [vim plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=cscope&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search). Here is one designed to handle big projects: [SourceCodeObedience](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1638)

There is a brief description of how to [grep text](http://www.railmoon.com/sourcecodeobedience/cscope-text) using [SourceCodeObedience](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1638).

Comment: vimgrep. I didn't invest the time in SCO for it to become useful.

Comment: This is the "right way" to do this, because this is the "vim way".

Comment: `vimgrep` opens a *single file* with match, instead of showing a buffer with "clickable" lines of matches. Besides, it doesn't support recursion. It's useless, I've no idea why would one prefer it to plain `grep` from command line, even with having to manually copy'n'open its results.

Answer (score 7):

I use grep directly for that.

```
grep -IirlZ "pattern" .|xargs -0 vim

-I: ignore binary
-i: ignore case
-r: recursive
-l: print file name only
-Z: print \0 after each file name
```

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check out `:vimgrep` and `:grep` in the vim documentation.  `:vimgrep` uses vim's own pattern searching functionality and reads all files into vim buffers.  `:grep` by default links to an external `grep` utlity on your system, but you can change the behavior by setting the  `grepprg` option.  Here's a link to the online docs:

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#grep

There's more info on that and also some other options in the tip on "Find in files within Vim" at the Vim Tips Wiki:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim

Answer (score 4):

Set `grepprg` to [Ack](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim), then use `:grep` to search with Ack.

Or use ctags.

Comment: [Universal ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) are definitely cool, but sometimes you want to just grep through for a text pattern, rather than search specifically for declarations/implementations. The link to Ack is broken.

Comment: I fixed the link. Ack is amazing btw, exactly what one would want from a grep integrated with vim: i.e. usual grep functionality + results are being opened in a separate buffer, and are "clickable".

Answer (score 3):

`Ag` is good option to search the pattern recursively.

https://github.com/rking/ag.vim

Comment: If it is part of `git` repo, `git grep` is a good option as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [:vimgrep](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:vimgrep) i.e.:

```
  :vimgrep /pattern/ **/*.py
```

Check this Vim Tip:

- [Find in files within Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim)

Also give a look to [grep.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=311), it's a plugin that integrates the grep, fgrep, egrep, and agrep tools with Vim and allows you to search for a pattern in one or more files and jump
to them...

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a source code index using [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and then VIM can [use this](http://www.faqs.org/docs/ldev/0130091154_64.htm) to navigate seamlessly through your code base. It's source code aware in that you can jump directly to method declarations etc.

You need to regenerate the ctags files every so often, but you can do that as part of your make process. It should be pretty fast unless your code base is sizeable.

Comment: How does this help to find symbol reference?

Comment: ctags will index your source code (in most languages). VIM has the capability to navigate via the ctags index, so you can position yourself over whatever symbol and then jump directly to the definition. Ctrl + ], I think.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody's mentioned it, but I use tend nowadays to use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)